# Does (int)myDouble ever differ from (int)Math.Truncate(myDouble)?

Tags: c#, .net, math

Does `(int)myDouble` ever differ from `(int)Math.Truncate(myDouble)`?

Is there any reason I should prefer one over the other?

Comment: My naïve guess would be that the latter is an unambiguously defined aspect of the CLR API, while the former depends on the language specification, even though it's implicitly the same.

Comment: I would think that using `Math.Truncate` is an unneeded step.

Comment: `Math.Truncate` is intended for when you need to keep your result as a `double` with no fractional part. If you want to convent it to an `int`, use the cast.

Comment: @Douglas is exactly right.  Using `Math.Truncate` can also make it very clear to anyone reading your code that you really do intend to truncate instead of round or assume that it's always an integral value.  However, I wouldn't recommend this - that's what comments are for.

Comment: The C# language spec is a bit weak here.  Overflow, NaN and Infinity are corner cases that are imperfectly documented in the unchecked case.  But you're likely to get away with it.

Comment: To test it, try a `myDouble` that is `NaN`, one that is infinite, one that is finite but too huge for an `Int32`, e.g. `myDouble = 1e12`. Finally, try a value that is just below an integer but whose representation with 15 digits' precision is an integer, like `myDouble = 42.000000000000021` (be sure to include the correct number of zeroes). If all these are equivalent, there's a good chance the two operations always agree.

Comment: Eh, I think `myDouble = 41.999999999999979` is more relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Math.Truncate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx) is intended for when you need to keep your result as a double with no fractional part. If you want to convent it to an int, just use the cast directly.

**Edit**: For reference, here is the relevant documentation from the “[Explicit Numeric Conversions Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx)”:

> When you convert from a double or float value to an integral type, the value is truncated.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by **Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams** `(int)myDouble` will fail in the same way as `(int)Math.Truncate(myDouble)` when myDouble is too large.

So there is no difference in output, but `(int)myDouble` is working faster.

Comment: +1: This answer raises a pertinent point. Except that you need to remove the `(int)` cast from the truncated double, since you’d otherwise end up in the same situation.

Comment: Couldn't we use `(long)` if we expected the number to be quite large?

Comment: @Mark there is also class called `Decimal`, for such purposes - it should work fine as well.